# Google Foobar: Attribute Error when submitting solution

Tags: python, google-search, attributeerror, python-datetime

I've been a reading the site for many year and today is my first question.

I was invited to play in Google Foobar for searching Python, as I was testing my new found knowledge after finishing a tutorial.

When I submit my 'solution.py' I get the following error:
AttributeError on line 13

This code runs fine in Eclipse

This is the code:

```
from itertools import permutations
import time

x, y, z = 3, 19, 19
values = [x, y, z]
perm_obj = permutations(values)

for v in perm_obj:
    try:
        if time.strptime(str(v), '(%m, %d, %y)'): #This is line 13
            my_output.append(v)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Edit: perm_obj is the result of [itertools `permutation` method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
itertools.permutations(iterable, r=None)
```

Edit:  I changed the code a little to show how perm_obj looks like.  I hope this helps.

Code:

```
from itertools import permutations
from datetime import datetime

def answer(x, y, z):

    values = [x, y, z]
    perm_obj = permutations(values)
    my_output = []

    for v in perm_obj:
        try:
            print(v)
            datetime.strptime(str(v), '(%m, %d, %y)')
            my_output.append(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Output:

```
(19, 19, 3)
(19, 3, 19)
(19, 19, 3)
(19, 3, 19)
(3, 19, 19)
(3, 19, 19)
```

Comment: please provide one example of v? or perm_obj

Comment: Ravi, I edited my original post above.

Comment: If your code is just 10 lines, the error in line 13 must be in Google's code :)

Comment: This is not the entire code, there's a little more before this :-)  This code is in a function and takes a, y, z as arguments.  So there's the function definition and some import statements before.

Comment: Ooh!! I Added a #comment next to what line 13 is.  Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: In the future, you'll get faster responses if you actually include the whole error message, instead of just the error type and a meaningless line number.

Comment: @HenryKeiter, you are right, having the whole error message is better, but this is all Google Foobar shows -sorry-.  The code runs fine in Eclipse, so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `time` is an instance of `datetime.time`, which doesn't have a `strptime` method. Since you're constructing a date, you probably want it to be `datetime.datetime` instead.

```
import datetime
if datetime.datetime.strptime(str(v), '(%m, %d, %y)'):
    # etc
```

or equivalently:

```
from datetime import datetime
if datetime.strptime(str(v), '(%m, %d, %y)'):
    # etc
```

Comment: Let me try that! Thanks

Comment: I understand and it works too, but it still doesn't like that line.

Comment: @Alex If you post the full error message instead of just a tiny portion of it, it will help greatly in the debugging process. Not just the type and line, but the whole message and traceback.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up, you are correct having more information to help debug is helpful however, this is all the error message Google Foobar shows: AttributeError on line 13.  The code runs just fine in Eclipse.  The rest of the code is after what's shown above.  I hope this help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like the foo.bar project does not like the imported datetime module.  I took it off and re-wrote some code to do what time.strptime() was doing and it started working.

Unfortunately, my code did not pass and I ran out of time to submit :'''(

I hope I get another invite.